# MySQL Stored Procedure Variable as Table Name concatenated

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, concatenation

I have the following query I want to execute in my stored procedure WITHOUT PREPARING the query, since this gives me problems with OUT to pass back parameters.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE Test (
    IN CID BIGINT(20),
    IN IDs LONGTEXT
    )
BEGIN
    #EXECUTE UNDERNEATH QUERY
    SELECT * FROM CONCAT('Part1_OfTableName', CID); #CID IS CustomerID
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

However, this fails and I don't know how to fix the problem.

***(Note that in the example I have no spaces in my table name, however in my situation I might have a space in my table name though)***

Comment: You cannot vary a table name dynamically without constructing a query from a string... that you'll have to PREPARE.

Comment: @Uueerdo I have that right now, but that makes my OUT parameters unable to retrieve... (Returns me the error: **out of sync**)

Comment: As @Uueerdo mentioned you can't do this. All identifiers (table, column names and such) are static in MySql. What `OUT` parameters are you referring to? The code you provided doesn't contain any.

Comment: @peterm, indeed the provided code doesn't, just to keep it more simple and readable for others. I have some OUT parameters though as INT, VARCHAR etc. Is it also possible to return a result set with an OUT parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PREPARE` should have no bearing on your ability to successfully set `OUT` parameters of your procedure

```sql
SET DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test(IN cid INT, IN ids TEXT, OUT out_int INT)
BEGIN  
  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM `table_', cid, '`', CASE WHEN ids IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(' WHERE id IN( ', ids, ')') END);

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

  SET out_int = 1;
END//
SET DELIMITER ;
```

Sample usage:

```
mysql> CALL test(1, '2,3', @out_int);
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    2 |
|    3 |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @out_int;
+----------+
| @out_int |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to return results from a stored procedure using sql statement that must be prepared, you can use an intermediate temp table.

```
BEGIN

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `myresults` blah blah....;
//construct and prepare select you would've used, but start it with an insert like so...
// INSERT INTO `myresults` SELECT ....

// Execute the prepared query
SELECT * FROM `myresults`;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE `myresults`;
END
```

*...at least I am pretty sure this technique used to work; I've been working more in MSSQL the last couple years.*

Something to note:

- Temporary tables are connection/session specific, so while safe from a global perspective using a generic name like `myresults` can be problematic if queries executed earlier on the connection/session (or by a procedure calling this one) use the same name; in practice/paranoia, I tended to use a different guid (in each procedure using this technique) as a prefix for any temporary tables generated within it.

Comment: Great, so this will make me able to still use my OUT parameters? I will give it a try

Comment: I don't see any OUT parameters in your example; I was assuming you were talking about resultsets.

Comment: I am also interested in getting the resultset out. Most likely in combination with some OUT parameters such as INT's and VARCHAR's

Comment: It would really depend on how/what you want to assign to those parameters; presumably you could use the information from the `myresults` table to fill them out before dropping it.